ffmpeg on Ubuntu 22.04 always sets subtitle track to default even with 'disposition:s:0 0' command
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and installed ffmpeg 4.3.1. Entering the following command to copy an mkv file as 1 video track, 1 audio track defaulted, and 1 subtitle track not defaulted, but the result always has both audio & subtitle tracks defaulted.
-map 0:0 -c:v copy -metadata:s:v:0 language=eng -map 1:1 -c:a copy  -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -disposition:a:0 default -map 2:2 -c:s copy -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -disposition:s:0 0 -y

Edit: removing the "-y" at the end seems have solved it.
